# Cache table on one side of datalink in Oracle

Tags: caching, oracle11g

I would like to create a cached copy of a table via dblink in oracle. The story is the following:

I have two tables (employee, work) which are joined via a third table (emloyee_work) in a remote database. The reason for that is to decouple the connection between the two entities so that they are not able to be connected directly.

To handle the data easily we have a view that connects the tables via the join table. One can argue that this is the same as having the join table in the same database as the other two but that in not the point right now.

On a new site, the db link latency is very high which causes a major drop in performance since for every select the view is built and a select is executed for each employee through the db link.

The structure has relative high read count and low write count.

The question is whether there is a possibility to "mirror" or copy the remote join table to the local database? This copy should be temporary and should not be persisted.

This way the view would be executed on the local copy.

EDIT: Oracle version is 11gR2

Comment: Is the execution plan the same as for sites that don't have the problem? I'm not sure why you'd notice a difference if the tables are small. But this might be a case where the `driving_site` hint might make a difference, or just referencing the remote table directly instead of through the view. Also not sure quite what you're doing - are you doing lots of individual selects inside a loop? It sounds like you think you want a PL/SQL table, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use refreshed on demand [materialized views](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/01/03/understanding-materialized-view-in-oracle/).
See also [this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_materialized_view_using_database_link.htm) where they talk about implementing a materialized view over a dblink.

Since you are using Oracle 11g, you may create an [ad-hoc, RAM-based Materialized View](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle_11g_result_cache_sql_hint.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately materialized views are not an option since they get persisted.

Comment: @pentike doesn't a "local copy" imply persistence to some degree?  You can refresh the mat view whenever you feel necessary.

Comment: Yes it does, but the requirement is not to store any data on persistent storage so if the power goes out, no part of the join table remains at the remote site. I know that does not make much sense in the view of the original intent, but it was not my call.

Comment: @Sebas this ram based materialized view sounds promising, I will check it out.